# Using Firebase, Material Design Components (MDC), and Node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, webpack, google-cloud-functions, mdc-components

## Overview

I'm working on a website (multi-page) for a friend and I've decided to use Google's Material Design Components (MDC) for the Web as the base of its styling. I would like for it to be hosted on Firebase, using Functions and Hosting.

I have been working on it for a little more than a week and have gotten to the point where I can use **Node.js**, **Express**, and **EJS** to render multiple pages, but I can't seem to understand how MDC would become functional in this environment.

---

## Question

Have you seen this work before? If so, how was it done and where should I begin?

---

#### Side-Note

I have been able to get it to run locally using [this quide](https://material.io/develop/web/docs/getting-started/). Here's the main files that make this work:

**webpack.config.js**

```js
module.exports = [{
entry: './app.scss',
output: {
    // This is necessary for webpack to compile
    // But we never use style-bundle.js
    filename: 'style-bundle.js',
},
module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
            {
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: 'bundle.css',
                },
            },
            { loader: 'extract-loader' },
            { loader: 'css-loader' },
            {
                loader: 'sass-loader',
                options: {
                    includePaths: ['./node_modules']
                }
            },
        ]
    }]
},
}];
```

**index.html**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bundle.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button class="foo-button mdc-button">
        Button
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material/button": "^0.36.0",
    "firebase-admin": "~5.12.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "eslint": "^4.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0",
    "extract-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.3",
    "webpack": "^3.12.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

**app.scss**

```css
@import "@material/button/mdc-button";

.foo-button {
  @include mdc-button-ink-color(teal);
  @include mdc-states(teal);
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty vague description.  Is there a specific problem you're running into?

Comment: My apologies, I will make it clearer now.

Comment: @DougStevenson I reformatted the question.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're asking. Isn't it just some JS and styling?

Comment: Unfortunately not in the case of hosting on Firebase. I reached around in their community Slack and found a helpful answer.
I'm going to be using React instead - MDC has a React project configuration you can use. https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A member of the Firebase Slack was able to point me in the right direction, so I am no longer in need of assistance. Provided is a link to a screenshot of what they suggested.

[Sam Jackson's Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIQqv.png)

Basically, I'm going to be using React instead of plain ol' Node.js. They seem to have developed a version of MDC for React that you can configure when creating a React project.

[MDC React GitHub](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-react)

Comment: There still seems to be a conflict.  MDC seems to need the server to be run with `webpack-dev-server` (the `npm start` command essentially runs this).  However, when performing local testing with Firebase hosting, the example code says to run `firebase serve --only hosting`.  How did you resolve the conflict?

Comment: The answer to my question might be https://stackoverflow.com/a/39554878/2848676 where it basically says you don't use `webpack-dev-server`.  Instead you essentially call `webpack` (via `npm run build`) which puts all the files in a place that `firebase serve` and `firebase deploy` know to look.  Firebase knows to look there by configuration in `firebase.json`.